# ES6 : How to push unique values in an Array while adding the duplicate ones?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "amount": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Tomato",
    "amount": 10
  }
]
```

Requirement is when I push a object like

```
{
   "name": "Apple",
   "amount": 10
}
```

Expected Result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "amount": 15
  },
  {
    "name": "Tomato",
    "amount": 10
  }
]
```

But on pushing unique entry like `{"name":"Orange","amount":15}`, the resulting array should be:

```
[{"name":"Apple","amount":5},{"name":"Tomato","amount":10},{"name":"Orange","amount":15}]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode : 
1) check if the entry exists. 
2) get the index   
3) if exist update the array of objects  
3) if not exist Push the entry to the array of objects

```
const x = [{"name":"Apple","amount":5},{"name":"Tomato","amount":10}]
const toPush =  {"name":"Apple","amount":30}


//(1 & 2) it would return a value greater than  or equal to 0 if it exist
var indx= x.findIndex(q=>q.name == toPush.name)

// 3
if( getIndex >= 0 ) {
   x[indx] = toPush
}

// 4
else {
  x.push(toPush)
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I guess reason for the vote could be that this could be achieved in better ways and must have be addresses already. We should look for such posts and close this one